# does include works with array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i'm trying to use includes to see if an object is inside the array like so:

```
arr=[{name:'Dan',id:2}]
```

and I want to check like so:

```
arr.includes({name:'Dan',id:2})
```

and this returns false, is there a way to do that?

Comment: It might sound surprising, but In javascript, these two objects are NOT equal. So you have to have a function that accepts two objects and tells true when _you_ think they're the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does include works with array of objects?

Yes — if you use the **same** object as the argument to `includes` that's in the array:

```js
const obj = {name: "Dan", id: 2};
const arr = [{name: "T.J.", id: 42}, obj, {name: "Joe", id: 3}];
console.log(arr.includes(obj));                  // true
console.log(arr.includes({name: "Dan", id: 2})); // false
```

`includes` uses a `===` check, and `o1 === o2` is only ever true when `o1` and `o2` refer to the **same** object. In your example, you're using two different but equivalent objects instead.

For your use case, you probably want `some`, which lets you execute a callback to determine whether an entry in the array matches a condition:

```
if (arr.some(e => e.id === 2)) {
```

Example:

```js
const obj = {name: "Dan", id: 2};
const arr = [{name: "T.J.", id: 42}, obj, {name: "Joe", id: 3}];
console.log(arr.some(obj => obj.id === 2));      // true
```

There are various ways to spin that, depending on what you want the check to be (which are discussed at length in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)), but that just means adjusting the contents of the function you pass `some`.

Comment: Wow, this is better. `:)` I had the same question. By reference vs Value right?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - The check in `includes` is `===` (which I should have said above, and will :-)). `o1 === o2` is only ever true when `o1` and `o2` both contain references to the same object. (Variables hold object references, which are values. Though there are other interpretations...)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman: "by reference" and "by value" mean something different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy . It's not applicable here.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh okay... Are Object references not the "by reference" then?

Comment: @FelixKling - :-) I chose to skirt around that, and probably shouldn't have. Good link.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - No, it's just the word "reference" being used for different things (a reference to an *object* is not the same thing as a reference to a *variable*, which is what "by reference" relates to).

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman: In a nutshell: "* by reference/value" describes the relationship between variables/parameters. It has nothing to do with the actual values involved. Values can either be "reference-type" values (like object) or "value-type" values (primitives): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type . So, JavaScript is a "* by value" language which implements objects as reference-type values.

Answer (score 2):

Not like that. Use `some` instead:

```
arr.some(obj => obj.id === 2)
```

Which checks if there is an object with `id` equals to `2`.

If you are checking for both `id` and `name` then:

```
arr.some(obj => obj.id === 2 && obj.name === "Dan")
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do have [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function, but for your case, you have to do using `some()`:

```
arr.some(e => e.id === 2 && e.name === "Dan")
arr.some(e => e.name === "Dan")
```

Comment: Probably *"but it just checks for primitive values"*, which is incorrect. Alternately, it could be because there are already two answers using `some`, which suggests when you find you're posting it for the third time, probably best to delete.

Comment: Yeah, it uses Same-value-zero equality

Comment: @DerekPollard Wow, what's that?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value_equality

Comment: @DerekPollard Thanks mate! `:)`