# How to add object to array and also remove it when user clicks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

when user presses a button am just adding the data to an state, and now when user represses it i need to remove the data / and do not let the data to be added to the array ? Am using this on react native !

```
My state; 

state = { selected = [] };
```

Now the function to all data to state;

```
Handler(data){       
     cont {selected } = this.state;

        if(!selected.includes(data))
            {
                this.setState({ selected : [...selected, data] })
                
            }else{
                const index = selected.indexOf(data);
                if (index > -1) {
                    const selection = selected ;
                    selection.splice(index, 1);
                    this.setState({ selected : selection });
                }
            }
    }
```

But, above keeps on adding the data, as am sending the data as object

```
Data sent to above function, {available: 'true'}
```

So, how to do this ? check if the object already presented and remove it ? It works when i pass array like "[true]", but its not working when i pass object !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748605/does-include-works-with-array-of-objects This will help regarding `includes` function which does the check. If the data is being added to the state, that means there is some problem with the condition right? check what includes offers to you.

Comment: You are mutating your state here `const selection = selected; selection.splice(...` you need to, at the very least clone the state array `const selection = [...selected];` but better to do it in the `setState` call `setState(prevSelected => *update logic*)`