# Why .includes() is not working on my object array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter a nested object array with poor result.

`.includes` won't find my search element even though it is present in the array. I would be grateful for your help!

```js
const date = { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' };

const customers = 
  [ { first_name: 'Doris'
    , orders: 
      [ { product:
          { name: 'White shell', price: 10, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
            , { delivery_date: '2021-10-14' } 
        ] } } 
      , { product: 
          { name: 'Pink shell', price: 15, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
    ] } } ] } 
  , { first_name: 'Nemo'
    , orders: 
      [ { product: 
          { name: 'Carbonated water', price: 10, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
            , { delivery_date: '2021-10-14' } 
  ] } } ] } ];

const res = customers.filter(function(customer) {
  return customer.orders.some(function(order) {
    console.log(date, order.product.schedule, order.product.schedule.includes(date));
    return order.product.schedule.includes(date);
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Because `schedule` is an array of objects _containing_ dates, not an array of dates.

Comment: `includes` compares elements using `===`. This will not match because `date` is not the same *object* as the one in the array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748605/does-include-works-with-array-of-objects

Comment: How do I use `.some` instead of `.includes` in this case?

Comment: Oh man. That data structure is scary! :-o

Comment: @h-sifat not so much, you should take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of searching if the `schedule` array contains `date`, search for an element of `schedule` that have the same `delivery_date` as `date`.

```js
const date = { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' };

const customers = 
  [ { first_name: 'Doris'
    , orders: 
      [ { product:
          { name: 'White shell', price: 10, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
            , { delivery_date: '2021-10-14' } 
        ] } } 
      , { product: 
          { name: 'Pink shell', price: 15, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
    ] } } ] } 
  , { first_name: 'Nemo'
    , orders: 
      [ { product: 
          { name: 'Carbonated water', price: 10, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
            , { delivery_date: '2021-10-14' } 
  ] } } ] } ];

const res = customers.filter(function(customer) {
  return customer.orders.some(function(order) {
    return order.product.schedule.find(schedule => schedule.delivery_date === date.delivery_date) !== undefined;
// alternative :    return !!(order.product.schedule.find(schedule => schedule.delivery_date === date.delivery_date));
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `Array.map()` on `delivery_date` for that.
You weren't that far

```js
const date = { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' };

const customers = 
  [ { first_name: 'Doris'
    , orders: 
      [ { product:
          { name: 'White shell', price: 10, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
            , { delivery_date: '2021-10-14' } 
        ] } } 
      , { product: 
          { name: 'Pink shell', price: 15, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
    ] } } ] } 
  , { first_name: 'Nemo'
    , orders: 
      [ { product: 
          { name: 'Carbonated water', price: 10, schedule: 
            [ { delivery_date: '2021-10-07' } 
            , { delivery_date: '2021-10-14' } 
  ] } } ] } ];
  
const res = customers.filter(({orders}) =>
  orders.some( ({product}) =>
    product.schedule.map(({delivery_date}) => delivery_date)
      .includes(date.delivery_date)
  ) )


console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

> to show what `product.schedule.map()` do
> (as asked in here in a comment)

```js
const res = customers.filter(({orders}) =>
  orders.some( ({product}) =>
    {
    let tmp_array = product.schedule.map(({delivery_date}) => delivery_date)
    
    console.log(product.name, JSON.stringify(tmp_array) )
    
    return tmp_array.includes(date.delivery_date)
    }
  ) )
```

will return

```
White shell ["2021-10-07","2021-10-14"] 
Carbonated water ["2021-10-07","2021-10-14"]
```

this one is not showed:

```
Pink shell ["2021-10-07"]
```

because `White shell` allready contain your `delivery_date` (`2021-10-07`) and the `order.some()` doesn't need to test the next `product.schedule` array.

if you want to see it,
just change your data of `'White shell'--> '2021-10-07'`
to `'White shell'--> '2000-01-01'`

Comment: I need to digest that...I will have a shorter expression if I use arrow functions and object destructuring...but what magic does `map.`? Creates a new array based on every element in the calling array it says...I don't know how to `console.log` that...

Comment: @MattiasInokuchi I added the way to do this, and the interpretation of the result you will get here